# How to fix "undefined has no properties"?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, supabase

**Actual behavior:**

The account data is completely deleted from Supabase but it didn't logout automatically, and the console log says **undefined has no properties**.

**profile.vue:**

```
<script setup>
const deleteAccount = async () => {
    try {
        loggingOut.value = true
        const { error } = await $fetch('/api/account', {
            method: 'delete'
        })
        if (error) {
            throw error
        } else {
            const { error } = await client.auth.signOut()
            if (error) {
                throw error
            } else {
                return navigateTo('/login')
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        loggingOut.value = false
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}
<script>
```

**server/api/account.delete.ts:**

```
import {
    serverSupabaseServiceRole,
    serverSupabaseUser,
} from "#supabase/server";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const serviceRole = serverSupabaseServiceRole(event);
    const user = await serverSupabaseUser(event);
    const { error } = await serviceRole.auth.admin.deleteUser(`${user?.id}`);
    if (error) {
        throw createError({
            message: error.message,
        });
    }
});
```

**Expected behavior:**

The User clicks the delete account button and the account data will be completely deleted from Supabase and logout automatically.

Comment: Please check whether the variable has the right value before accessing its properties. This kind of error will arise if you are trying to access the properties of an undefined variable.

Comment: Where did you define loggingOut and client ? and are you sure they are correctly initialized ?

Comment: @Billuc i defined the loggingOut like this const loggingOut = ref(false), just for the loader component <o-loading v-model:active="loggingOut" iconSize="large" label="Logging out..." />

Comment: @SufailKalathil is it the all the files in server/api/ must return something? because i tried to return the data of the deleteUser() and it works. Modified codes as below:
```const { data, error } = await serviceRole.auth.admin.deleteUser(`${user?.id}`);```
added `return data;` to last line